# Why are my Script Bundles only working on Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have deployed my app to my IIS server.  The javascript/css seem to work when I browse the webpage from the IIS server (although some of the css seems to not be loading as well).  However, when I go to another machine and view the webpage from a client, none of the Javascript seems to be enabled.  The links to the scripts are there, and when I type their path into the browser, I am able to retrieve the file (so it's not a permissions issue or a path issue).  Yes the browser I am viewing the page from has javascript enabled (it's my dev machine where everything works if I'm working from visual studio).

Can anyone help me figure out what is happening here?  Everything works fine in my dev machine.

---

### Edit

Ok I have tried everything I can find on the interwebs.  I have tried adding the 'bundle' module, removing then adding (as below), I have tried with and without 'runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests', I have tried enableing and disabling the

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

Nothing seems to work.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
    <remove name="BundleModule" />
    <add name="BundleModule" type="System.Web.Optimization.BundleModule" />
    <!-- any other modules you want to run in MVC e.g. FormsAuthentication, Roles etc. -->
</modules>
```

I just don't understand why IIS7 would be doing something different when you browse the website locally on the server and another thing when you browse the site on different machine?

---

### Edit 2

Even more baffling.  I figured there might be something wrong with bundling (some assembly not loaded correctly who knows) so to test the theory, I commented out all the bundling code on my layout and replaced it with hard coded links to the styles/javascript.  Again, it works in development, it works when previewing on the server, but when you go to a client machine, none of the javascript seems to work!!!  I've installed it on two different IIS servers now... still same problem!

---

### Edit 3

Unbelievable.  It looks like the problem is... drum roll.  IE10.  I am using integrated authentication so I was only using IE.  Until I realised that chrome can prompt/pass credentials as well.  So I opened the site from Chrome and no problem!  I compared the html from my local version on my dev machine to the html coming from the server, and other than the fact that the URLs have an extra element in the path (the site is deployed to a virtual directory) the html is identical.  So for whatever reason, IE has decided that it will not run javascript from my IIS server, but it will from every other website on the internet.  I even used fiddler to double check that all of the css/javascript was being fetched and received (they are, even checked the temporary files folder after a clean sweep to see if the css/js was downloaded).  So, as usual, IE is a piece of crap causing nothing but headache and misery.  Now to figure out how to fix this (my organisation is 80% IE).

Comment: Are you using the same URLs when browsing the application in local or remote?

Comment: You mean relative to the website location?  Yes all paths are relative.  Someone suggested to use BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; in the bundleconfig.  When I did this on my dev box and ran it in Visual Studio, I get the same problem as on the server.

Comment: It seems that for whatever reason, the optimization does something weird when it encounters:
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/tablesorter/css").Include(
                        "~/Content/bootstrap.2.3.1.css",
"~/Content/TableSorter/css/theme.bootstrap.css"));

Comment: ok, so it turns out there was a path content/tablesorter/css that actually exists so MVC bundler didn't like that.  I changed the name of the bundle and now with enableoptimizations everything works... in development.  Now, when I view the website from the IIS server, it looks perfect... however when I view it from anywhere else, I still have javascript/css missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for anyone out there who might run into the same issue and has to work with IE I solved the problem by adding this to my _layout.cshtml:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

What this does is instructs IE to use the latest available rendering engine to process the html (in other words don't try to be smart and guess what my html is built for).  So it essentially tells the versions of IE that have 'compatibility mode' to not use it.

For me this works fine because our organization is small and we are usually within one version of the latest release of IE.  If the latest version causes issues, I can easy fix and deploy with no harm done.  However, this IS NOT optimal for a general purpose website or organization with high numbers of users on a variety of IE browsers.

Comment: YOU SONOFABITCH I COULD KISS YOU FOR THAT

Comment: Thanks!!!!  I'm not entirely clear on why this is necessary, but this definitely worked.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem too.

I found was that Internet Explorer was set to "high" when browsing the internet when using our corporate network. Once I added my site to the trusted sites zone, everything worked.

You can check if your site in the Trusted Sites zone, but going to **Internet Options** -> **Security** -> **Sites**

[image]